# chart n d3js without posting data on google analytics server

Tags: javascript

I want to create some interactive charts for one of my web application using d3.js but on analyzing  found that the d3.js puts data on google analytics server and I want to know that how we can stop the data being flown to third party server like Google and still implement the chart.

Comment: d3js has got nothing to do with Google Analytics. you should check the documentation and example on http://d3js.org/